# Complex modulus Inequality using $|exp(z)-1|$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

I think I am almost there:

> Prove $\left|z\right|/4 < \left|\exp(z)-1\right|<7\left|z\right|/4$ for all $0<|z|<1$.

**MY ADVANCES** First we note that 
$$
\left|\exp(z)-1\right| = \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\right|= \left|z+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\right|
$$
Then by using both sides of the triangle inequality we get
$$
\left|z\right|-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\left|z\right|^n}{n!} \leq \left|\exp(z)-1\right|\leq \left|z\right|+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\left|z\right|^n}{n!}.
$$
Then we only need to prove that if $0<\left|z\right|<1$ then 
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\left|z\right|^n}{n!} < \frac{3}{4}\left|z\right| \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \    (1)
$$
**Where I am Stuck** But here is as far as I have come, I can't get this last inequality, since I only get that 
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\left|z\right|^n}{n!} < e-2
$$
Any hint to prove (1)? Is this the way on proving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $0  <|z| < 1$,

$$\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{|z|^n}{n!} \le \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{|z|}{n!} = (e - 2)|z| < \frac{3}{4}|z|.$$

Comment: Nice and easy. Thanks @kobe