# Proof Verification: For $\|z\|< \epsilon, \|e^z - 1\|\geq \|z\|(1 - \epsilon)$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

*Background*: There is a proof on p. 18 of *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function* (Titchmarsh, 2nd Ed.).  The proof asserts (without proving) that $\|e^z - 1\| > A\|z\|$.  I am *very* rusty at mathematics (got my degree 43+ years ago), so for practice I wanted to prove that assertion.

I found a proof [Complex modulus Inequality using $|exp(z)-1|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1234938/477210) where they prove that $\|e^z - 1\| > \|z\|/4$. Of course, that works. But I was hoping to prove a closer estimate after noting l'Hospital's Rule:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{(e^z - 1)}{z}=
\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{f(z)=(e^z - 1)}{g(z)=z}=
\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{f'(z)}{g'(z)}=
\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{e^z}{1}=1.
\end{equation}

(I never could work out a $\|z\|< \epsilon$ style proof using the l'Hospital result.)

*Request*. I provide my proof below and ask: (1) Please check my proof for accuracy (comments to improve my proof also very welcome).  2) Any suggestions for alternate proofs?

*Theorem*: For $\|z\|< \epsilon, \|e^z - 1\|\geq \|z\|(1 - \epsilon)$.

*Proof*. We have:

\begin{equation}\frac{e^z -1}{z}=\frac{(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}) -1}{z}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}}{z}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^{k-1}}{k!}=1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{z^{k-1}}{k!}.\end{equation}

Now fix $\epsilon$ and we have:

\begin{equation}\left\|\frac{e^z -1}{z}\right\|=\frac{\left\|e^z -1\right\|}{\|z\|}=\left\|1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{z^{k-1}}{k!}\right\|=\left\|1-\left(-\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{z^{k-1}}{k!}\right)\right\|\geq\|1\|-\left\|(-\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{z^{k-1}}{k!})\right\|=\|1\|-\left\|(\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{z^{k-1}}{k!})\right\|\geq\|1\|-\left\|(\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\|z^{k-1}\|}{k!})\right\|\geq\|1\|-\left\|\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\epsilon}{k!}\right\|=\end{equation}
\begin{equation}=1-\epsilon\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}=1-\epsilon(e-2)\geq1-\epsilon.\end{equation}

Thus, $\|e^z -1\|\geq\|z\|(1-\epsilon)$.

Comment: That looks great!

Comment: What does $\|z\|$ mean?

Comment: @Jack: It means the complex modulus or absolute value.  I know it is often with single vertical lines but with my limited knowledge of LaTex I found it easier to format the correct heights using the double lines.

Comment: You could simply use `$\left|$` and `$\right|$` between formulas.

Comment: The $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{e^z-1}{z}$ converges to $1$ means for every $\epsilon$ there is $\delta$ such that for $|z| < \delta$, $\left|\frac{e^z-1 }{z}-1\right| < \epsilon$. And hence $|e^z-1 - z| \ < \ \epsilon |z|$ and $|e^z-1| > (1-\epsilon) |z|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proof-verification (some steps are tailored.)`

> *Proof*. We have:
>
> \begin{equation}\frac{e^z -1}{z}=\frac{(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}) -1}{z}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}}{z}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^{k-1}}{k!}=1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{z^{k-1}}{k!}.\end{equation}
>
> Now fix $\epsilon>0$ and we have `by the triangle inequality`
>
> \begin{align}
> &\left\|1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{z^{k-1}}{k!}\right\|
> =\left\|1-\left(-\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{z^{k-1}}{k!}\right)\right\|\\
> =&\|1\|-\left\|\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{z^{k-1}}{k!}\right\|\\
> \geq &1-\left\|\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\|z^{k-1}\|}{k!}\right\| \quad\ \ \text{(why?)}\\
> \geq &1-\left\|\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\epsilon}{k!}\right\|\quad\text{(why?)}\\
> = &1-\epsilon\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}=1-\epsilon(e-2)\geq1-\epsilon.\end{align}
>
> Thus, $\|e^z -1\|\geq\|z\|(1-\epsilon)$.

---

`Looks good. The first "why" deserves some explanation and the second "why" can be easily fixed.`

Comment: I like both your comments and your reformatting.  On your first why, is it enough to reference the $|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$ version of the triangle inequality?  On your second why, how about $|z^{k-1}| \leq |z| < \epsilon$?

Comment: @TMurphy: I think one needs a limiting argument for the first "why". The triangle inequality only works for the finite sum. For the second one, you would need $\epsilon<1$ as well.